# Trying to find the optimal parameters for my function using scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python

I am trying to find the optimal parameters, a, b, d, e and f in my function using the scipy.optimize.minimize module but I can't get past this error. My code and the error are shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import minimize
     
delx=np.zeros(1)
dely=np.zeros(1)  
   
def func(x, a, b, d, e, f):
   
    delx = np.cos(a*x+b) + d*np.cos(e*x+f)     # d = r/R
    dely = np.sin(a*x+b) + d*np.sin(e*x+f)
    rad = np.sqrt(delx*delx+dely*dely)
    y=np.arccos(delx/rad)
    ysign1=np.sign(dely)
    ysign2=(1.-ysign1)/2.
    y=ysign2*2.*np.pi+ysign1*y
    y=y*180./np.pi
    return y

def main():

    ..... #This section just opens a folder and retrieves the x3data and y3data and does some 
    manipulation not relevant to the question.

   
    guess=np.zeros(5)
    guess[0]=0.5376315     #a
    guess[1]=5.96413985     #b
    #guess[2]= -0.82777015       #c   
    guess[2]= 0.17739102       #d
    guess[3]=5.95233689    #e
    guess[4]=-8.88116461      #f
    a=0.
    b=0.
    d=0.
    e=0.
    f=0.
    x0 = guess
    res = minimize(func(x, a, b, d, e, f), x0, args=(x3data, y3data), method='nelder-mead')
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I think it may have something to do with the brackets around guess=np.zeros(5) but I am not sure. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: WHERE, exactly, do you get that error?  I'm going to try to fix your indentation, but you should check it.

Comment: The problem is that `minimize` expects its first parameter to be a FUNCTION.  You are calling a function, and passing its return value, which is an array.  You need to pass simply `func`, and pass the extra arguments in the `args` parameter, as `args=(a,b,c,d,e,f)`.  I'm not sure what you expect `x3data` and `y3data` to do.

Comment: x3data and y3data are lists that are fed to the function.

Comment: I get that error on the line res = minimize(func(x, a, b, d, e, f), x0, args=(x3data, y3data), method='nelder-mead')

Comment: I think you want something like `res = minimize(func, x0...)` and `def func(x):`.  `x` will be a vector with the current guess.  You don't need a, b, c, d, e, f, and I don't know what you're expecting `x3data` and `y3data` to do.

Comment: Previously, I was using the code: popt3, pcov3 = curve_fit(func, x3data, y3data,p0=guess),
to find the best fitting parameters. Now i want to use the minimize function to do the same. Sorry my python skills are very weak.

Comment: I suspect you do not want `x3data` and `y3data` at all with a minimize operation.   Have you tried simply `res = minimize(func, x0, method='nelder-mead')`?

Comment: Yes, I have got it working now thanks for your help. I had to change my function up a bit.